# Inject mock with Dagger for Espresso tests

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, dagger-2

I have tried modifying the code of this repo : [Chiuki's android test](https://github.com/chiuki/android-test-demo)
so it will fit Dagger's configuration for my project.

So What I did is :

1)  Adding a `Component` for `MainActivity` :

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = DemoApplication.ApplicationComponent.class)
public interface MainActivityComponent {

void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

Clock getClock();

}
```

2) Modifying `Application` class to create and provide `ApplicationComponent` :

```
private ApplicationComponent component;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    component = createComponent();
    component.inject(this);
}

protected ApplicationComponent createComponent() {
return DaggerDemoApplication_ApplicationComponent.builder().build();
}

public ApplicationComponent component() {
return component;
}
```

3) Perform injection in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` :

```
DaggerMainActivityComponent.builder()
        .applicationComponent(((DemoApplication) getApplication()).component())
        .build()
        .inject(this);
```

and I can verify by running the app that it seems to working.

And now I'm trying to modify accordingly tests in `androidTest` folder so 
they will keep working.

First step was to change `createComponent()` method inside `MockDemoApplication` to provide the mock `Clock` instance :

```
@Override
protected ApplicationComponent createComponent() {
return DaggerDemoApplication_ApplicationComponent.builder()
        .clockModule(new ClockModule() {
          @Override
          Clock provideClock() {
            return Mockito.mock(Clock.class);
          }
        })
        .build();
}
```

And second step was to perform the injection in `MainActivityTest` inside `setUp()` method :

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
DemoApplication app
    = (DemoApplication) instrumentation.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();

DaggerMainActivityTest_TestComponent.builder()
        .mockClockModule(new MockClockModule())
        .build()
        .inject(this);

}
```

So now I'm running the next test but it fails with `AssertionFailedError` :

```
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 'with text: is "2008-09-23"' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with text: is "2008-09-23"
Got: "TextView{id=2131165184, res-name=date, visibility=VISIBLE, width=272, height=135, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=2017-11-22, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

I'm guessing that the injection worked, since the test is not crashing with a `NullPointerException`  when it calls clock instance, but somehow it is returning the

Comment: Expected value is `2008-09-23`, actual value is `2017-11-22`. This would give you a seam why the assertion fails.

Comment: Injection of the mock didn't work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong with Dagger?